# Bootstrap Tooltip - How can I access "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a function to show bootstrap tooltips based on the id of the link the user is hovering over.

Alerting this.id is blank inside the title function - do I need to pass **this** through and if so how? (this) doesn't work and I've tried a few other methods to no avail. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tooltiplink').tooltip({ 
    html: true,
    title: function() {
      return $('#' + this.id).html();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try $(this).attr("id") to get the value of the id for the respective element.

Comment: Try `this.html()` instead. Not sure what `.tooltip` will pass as `this`, but you hardly can influence it.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma: No, that's equivalent to `this.id` unless `this` is not a DOM element

Comment: I agree but sometime this.id doesnot work as it should @Bergi

Comment: not sure but seems to work for me: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L3EAY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)`. There is no need for using `$('#' + this.id)`.
`$(this)` is already the element you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tooltiplink').tooltip({ 
    html: true,
    title: function() {
      return $(this).html();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: But if `this` *were* the element, then `this.id` wouldn't be blank?

Comment: @Bergi If that element doesnt have an id? Then it will be blank right?

Comment: Yup, only the questions sounds as if OP was expecting to see an id on all of his elements. Maybe that's the mistake :-)

Comment: Yes ID on all elements. Thanks for the answer and all contributions!